# Trial period for an employer, not employee

Tags: resignation

Is there such thing? E. g. I work for 3 months for a company and then resign it, because I didn't like it for some reasons. I mean it is not always possible to know in advance if project is interesting, especially given that employers tend to overestimate intrestingness of the project. So, more concretely, I wonder:
Is there such practice to give trial period to an employer so during that period employee could safely resign and no offence taken?

Comment: Can you please define what you mean by _employer_?  I'm pretty sure the CEO doesn't undergo a trial period

Comment: @Dawny33 well, a company I am planning to work for

Comment: So, you mean the company getting closed?

Comment: @Dawny33 no. I mean suppose I worked for a company for say 2 months and figured out that a project is not so interesting as I expected initially and that's why I wanna quit

Comment: You **need** to serve the notice period in that case.

Comment: Are you asking about legal / unemployment / redundancy information, or about professionalism?

Comment: Country matters here, and your profile says you're Ukrainian. If you don't edit the question, you're likely to get a bunch of US-specific answers.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I work in outsource (programming) for US/Europe customers, so I mostly interested the way hiring works in that regions, because Ukrainian companies adopt western culture (at least in my field)

Comment: Do you have probatation on your contracts? That almost always works both ways.

Comment: The critical part in your question seems to be "no offense taken" to which the answer is largely no. That said, this would need to be edited significantly to clarify exactly what you're asking about to consider reopening.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is very common in the UK, if nowhere else - during an employee's probation period, notice will typically be something like one week *on either side*; as you say, it's as much a trial for the benefit of the employee as it is for the employer.

Answer (score 5):

In Germany, a trial period goes for both parties. Employer *and* employee can end the contract with a way shorter notice period and without giving any reasons during the trial period.

"No offence taken" is something you cannot work out with a contract though. If you quit during probation, the company will most likely not give you glowing references but rather a short "worked here" statement. But what else can they do really?

Answer (score 5):

In the Netherlands, there is almost always a probation time ("proeftijd") of 1 month when you start working for an employer, sometimes longer (and sometimes there is no probation time).

During that period, *both parties* can end the employment relation at any moment, for any reason, with immediate effect.

Answer (score 4):

Same in France. There is a trial period, usually 3 months, sometimes 4, and which can be extended up to 7 months(that's new. 10 years ago, it could go up to 9 months). And as long as the employer can fire the employee within 48 hours, the employee can leave in 48 hours. Without anything else to pay than the days that have been done.

Statistics show that employees are using this possibility **far more often** than employers. Yet usually want the shortest trial time possible. While employers rarely(but not never) use the tool, yet want it usually as long as possible.

7 months can seem long, but once it's over, cutting the contract is a pain. Doable, but really painful(from here comes the reputation of rigidity of the french work market, which is not totally undeserved).